# getting value of Radio Button with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have defined radio buttons as bellow

```
<tr>
   <th height="35" scope="row">
       <div align="left">Response for Instruction</div>
   </th>
   <th scope="row"><input name="a"  type="radio" value="Excellent" /></th>
   <th scope="row"><input name="a"  type="radio" value="Good" /></th>
   <th scope="row"><input name="a"  type="radio" value="Poor" /></th>
   <th scope="row"><input name="a"  type="radio" value="Needs Improvement " /></th>
</tr>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = $('#a').attr('value');
    alert(a);
}
```

but its showing undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("input:radio[name=a]:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
 $("input:radio[name=a]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qh6Et/3/

**code**

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var a     = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(a);
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
var a = $('input[name="a"]').attr('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will help...

```
$("input[@name=a]:checked").val();
```